# Port forwarding on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ip, port-forwarding

I have got a VPS server with Ubuntu. It has got a static, public IP address. Here is `uname -a`:

```
Linux VPS 3.13.0-88-generic #135-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 8 21:10:42 UTC 2016            x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I want to use a Remote Administration Tool on it to manage my other VPSes. I need to forward port 1000, but how can I do this on Ubuntu?

By this I mean that the port will be visibly listening from an external host.